# Ajax call not executed by button click in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to refresh grid in partial view using AJAX call of button click. But click method of button is not working properly.

Following code snippet is code i am using to execute

JQUERY

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fromDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $("#toDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});

//function buttonClick() {

$("#btnSearch").click($.ajax({
    url: 'Report/SearchGrid',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (html) {}
}));

//}
    </script>
```

Razor Code

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onclick= "buttonClick();" style="width: 90px; border: solid 1px #1570a6; background-color: #1570a6; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 100;" />
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult SearchGrid(ExpenseReportModel model)
{
    ExpenseReportModel expModel = new ExpenseReportModel();
    expModel.ExpenseList = GetExpenseList();
    expModel.ExpenseFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.ExpenseFromDate);
    expModel.ExpenseToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.ExpenseToDate);

    return PartialView("_GridData", expModel.ExpenseList);
}
```

Comment: Yuo have a click handler attached and an onclick provided...? where is `buttonClick()` Also please explain what does "not working properly means"

Comment: it is not working even if i uncomment the function buttonClick() line

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from your code where you are passing data to the controller or where you are setting anything on your form with the result.  Your call should look something like this

```
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
         type: "POST",
         data: { from: $('.FromDate').val(), to: $('.ToDate').val() },
         cache: false,
         async: true,
         success: function (result) {
             $(".Content").html(result);
         }
     });
});
```

then in your controller you will accept parameters from and to instead of the whole model. You aren't doing a post back here so the whole model won't be sent back to the controller.  Let me know if you have any questions.